# How to Generate the View pragmatically to display the newly added view is displayed in first and previously added view displayed finally in android.?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, programmatically-created

I have one Button. If i click the button, the view has added pro grammatically.So the view has created. But I want some solution with some order.

Once If i click the button,the view has added accordingly. But i want to display the newly added view is displayed in first and previously added view displayed finally.

```
btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                      addRow();
            }
        });



private void addRow(){

   View hiddenInfo = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_order_detail, main_layout, false);
    main_layout.addView(hiddenInfo);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of layout is `main_layout`?

Comment: Its a Linear Layout.

Comment: Is there any keyword to display the view in reverse order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify a zero index for the new row:

```
main_layout.addView(hiddenInfo, 0);
```

Comment: But If added more layouts while i click the button,previous views also displayed.